# Why Ruby "RACK_ENV=test" deos not work for db:create to specify the test database？

Tags: ruby

I tried ty switch the RACK_ENV and RAILS_ENV environment from development to test by specifying the environment `RACK_ENV=test` variable ahead. But it still uses the development database when I type `rack db:create` How can I force it to use the test database? (postgres)

Comment: Have you tried `RACK_ENV=test rack db:create`? Or you've just setup `RACK_ENV=test` in your env?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to specify `ENV["RACK_ENV"]=test` in the app.rb file. As the rack keeps tracking the environment variables by not only your types in the running command but also in the files included in the Rackfile. If you have included app.rb in it. It could override your settings in the command.